# How to use the HTML button inside the canvas page?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

Hi everyone I'm planning to make the drag and drop method using the HTML5 canvas with j query but I'm stuck how to use the HTML button inside the canvas page. Has of now I'm able to get the image inside the canvas page and capable of doing drag and drop. But my plan is to use the button for drag and drop.

Here is my HTML page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    canvas{ border: 1px solid #808080; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("cvs1");
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("cvs2");

        var contexts=[];
        contexts.push(canvas1.getContext('2d'));
        contexts.push(canvas2.getContext('2d'));


        function clearAll(){
            //Clear both canvas first
            canvas1.width = canvas1.width
            canvas2.width = canvas2.width
        }

        canvas1.onclick=function(e){ handleClick(e,1); };
        canvas2.onclick=function(e){ handleClick(e,2); };
        //
        function handleClick(e,contextIndex){
            e.stopPropagation();

            var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-e.target.offsetLeft);
            var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-e.target.offsetTop);

            clearAll();

            for(var i=0;i<states.length;i++){

                var state=states[i];

                if(state.dragging){
                    state.dragging=false;
                    state.draw();
                    continue;
                }

                if ( state.contextIndex==contextIndex
                    && mouseX>state.x && mouseX<state.x+state.width
                    && mouseY>state.y && mouseY<state.y+state.height)
                {
                    state.dragging=true;
                    state.offsetX=mouseX-state.x;
                    state.offsetY=mouseY-state.y;
                    state.contextIndex=contextIndex;
                }

                state.draw();
            }
        }

        canvas1.onmousemove = function(e){ handleMousemove(e,1); }
        canvas2.onmousemove = function(e){ handleMousemove(e,2); }
        //
        function handleMousemove(e,contextIndex){
            e.stopPropagation();

            var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-e.target.offsetLeft);
            var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-e.target.offsetTop);

            clearAll();

            for(var i=0;i<states.length;i++){

                var state=states[i];

                if (state.dragging) {
                    state.x = mouseX-state.offsetX;
                    state.y = mouseY-state.offsetY;
                    state.contextIndex=contextIndex;
                }
                state.draw();
            }
        }


        var states=[];

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            states.push(addState(0,0,img));
        }
        img.src="http://www.rgraph.net/images/logo.png";




        function addState(x,y,image){
                state = {}
                state.dragging=false;
                state.contextIndex=1;
                state.image=image;
                state.x=x;
                state.y=y;
                state.width=image.width;
                state.height=image.height;
                state.offsetX=0;
                state.offsetY=0;
                state.draw=function(){
                    var context=contexts[this.contextIndex-1];
                    if (this.dragging) {
                        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
                        context.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.width+5,this.height+5)
                    }
                    context.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y);
                }
                state.draw();
                return(state);
        }

        $("#more").click(function(){
            states.push(addState(states.length*100,0,img));
        });


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="more">Add Image</button><br>
  <div>
  <canvas height="625" width="300" id="cvs1">[No canvas support]</canvas><br></div>

  <br><div><canvas height="125" width="700" id="cvs2">[No canvas support]</canvas></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NEBUr4REqIimcA4iunKM?p=preview

Comment: What do you mean by "use the HTML button inside the canvas page"?

Comment: @ Cassidy Williams I need to  use the button inside the canvas  page

Comment: @ Cassidy Williams The button should appear inside the canvas

Comment: In your demo I'm able to click the bar chart and drag it around. So it looks to me like you've made a "button" in the canvas element. What is the problem you're trying to solve? Is it not working in certain browsers?

Comment: @ericjbasti  Actually  i dont need that  html button  outside the canvas and the chart  which  appears in the canvas . These were the examples which i planned to show u people . I need oly the button inside the canvas which i can drag and drop only the button . U might have seen the example of visual basic where we use  properties to drag and drop. The same thing I'm planning to do  .so plz help me wit this.

Answer (score 0):

I have add style to `button` and `div`. 
I think this is what you want.

```js
 $(function() {

   var canvas1 = document.getElementById("cvs1");
   var canvas2 = document.getElementById("cvs2");

   var contexts = [];
   contexts.push(canvas1.getContext('2d'));
   contexts.push(canvas2.getContext('2d'));


   function clearAll() {
     //Clear both canvas first
     canvas1.width = canvas1.width
     canvas2.width = canvas2.width
   }

   canvas1.onclick = function(e) {
     handleClick(e, 1);
   };
   canvas2.onclick = function(e) {
     handleClick(e, 2);
   };
   //
   function handleClick(e, contextIndex) {
     e.stopPropagation();

     var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
     var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);

     clearAll();

     for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

       var state = states[i];

       if (state.dragging) {
         state.dragging = false;
         state.draw();
         continue;
       }

       if (state.contextIndex == contextIndex && mouseX > state.x && mouseX < state.x + state.width && mouseY > state.y && mouseY < state.y + state.height) {
         state.dragging = true;
         state.offsetX = mouseX - state.x;
         state.offsetY = mouseY - state.y;
         state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
       }

       state.draw();
     }
   }

   canvas1.onmousemove = function(e) {
     handleMousemove(e, 1);
   }
   canvas2.onmousemove = function(e) {
       handleMousemove(e, 2);
     }
     //

   function handleMousemove(e, contextIndex) {
     e.stopPropagation();

     var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
     var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);

     clearAll();

     for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

       var state = states[i];

       if (state.dragging) {
         state.x = mouseX - state.offsetX;
         state.y = mouseY - state.offsetY;
         state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
       }
       state.draw();
     }
   }


   var states = [];

   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() {
     states.push(addState(0, 0, img));
   }
   img.src = "http://www.rgraph.net/images/logo.png";




   function addState(x, y, image) {
     state = {}
     state.dragging = false;
     state.contextIndex = 1;
     state.image = image;
     state.x = x;
     state.y = y;
     state.width = image.width;
     state.height = image.height;
     state.offsetX = 0;
     state.offsetY = 0;
     state.draw = function() {
       var context = contexts[this.contextIndex - 1];
       if (this.dragging) {
         context.strokeStyle = 'red';
         context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width + 5, this.height + 5)
       }
       context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
     }
     state.draw();
     return (state);
   }

   $("#more").click(function() {
     states.push(addState(states.length * 100, 0, img));
   });


 }); // end $(function(){});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  padding: 20px;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position:relative;">
  <button id="more" style="position:absolute;top:6px;left:6px;">Add Image</button>
  <canvas height="625" width="300" id="cvs1">[No canvas support]</canvas>
  <br>
</div>

<br>
<div>
  <canvas height="125" width="700" id="cvs2">[No canvas support]</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: its all most  correct  but wat  i need is to  drag and drop only   the button . the images i showed oly for the example how it works . I need the same to the button .The same example wat we use  in the visual basic